# Const parameter is not const enough

Tags: c++, arrays, parameters, constants

This code

```
#include <array>

void foo(const int length) {
    std::array<int, length> arr;  //line 4
}


int main(){
    const int length = 10;
    std::array<int,length> arr;
}
```

fails with the error message

> : In function 'void foo(size_t)':
>
> :4:27: error: 'length' is not a constant expression
>
> ```
>  std::array<int, length> arr;
> ```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MMQXHx

The parameter `length` is marked as `const`.

Why is it not possible to pass the const length of a local `std::array` as a function parameter?

Why does it work in the main method?

I know, that a template approach like this would work

```
template <size_t length>
void foo() {
    std::array<int, length> arr;
}
```

Comment: @LordZsolt - A function argument cannot be declared `constexpr`.

Comment: "Constant expression" means more or less "known at compile time". It's not a synonym to "immutable".

Comment: @LordZsolt Saying that something who cannot be `constexpr` "needs to be `constexpr`" is at best misleading

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Deleted my comments so I won't mislead someone stumbling onto this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`const` does not mean "compile-time constant", or "constant expression".

It means "don't let me change the value of this runtime object".

*Sometimes* a `const` object can be considered constant "enough" for your needs, and the compiler will permit the code in those cases. A template argument is not one of those cases.

In `main`, [use `constexpr` instead](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01120730ac776f56); it's a keyword that was added to the language for this purpose.

That's not going to help you with `foo`, though, in which you simply can't do what you're trying to do. The equivalent is to make `foo` a function template, with `length` being a template parameter.